# How to display a selectlist in the title portion of a pageblock

Tags: apex, selectlist, pageblock

On my VF page I have a page block that contains a table inside it. I wanted to be able to put selectlists to filter the data in the table, and ideally I want to put them at the top of a pageblock so it doesn't take up and more area.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (despite its name), place any arbitrary content in a pageBlockButtons section. This allows you to also specify a title, like normal.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Section Title" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFilter}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterOptions}" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <!-- more code here -->
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't know that one would accept other content types. I'm gonna have to use that now :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible, but I'll warn you upfront that you'll need to do some CSS work to avoid it looking terrible. That said, you'll just need to use an apex:facet

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        whatever you want here
    </apex:facet>
</apex:pageBlock>
```